# Collada loader: Is there anyway to get several meshes from the scene object?

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I recently tried some experiments with Blender and the Collada Loader in three.js. In my Blender scene, I have three objects, but of course I only can manage one scene object with three.js with the loader. Everything works fine, even materials imported from Blender, but I was wondering if there is anyway to get the several objects from the scene object, turn them into three.js meshes, and then animate them individually, without turning them into several .dae files.

Posting my code here if it is useful:

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader(); 
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true; 
    loader.load( 'scene.dae', function ( collada ) {       
      dae = collada.scene;
      dae.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      dae.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
      scene.add(dae);     
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's neat ... I just asked @mrdoob himself on twitter. Gonna update as soon as we have an answer!

Comment: I posted it into the issues section of the three.js Github page a couple of days ago... but mrdoob himself closed it, so here we are xD

Comment: Did you check `collada.scene.traverse` in the example at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada_skinning.html

Answer (score 1):

If you `console.log(collada.scene)` you'll see that you have a child array. This is where all the meshes live.

E.g. you can access the first one like so:

```
collada.scene.children[0].children[0];
```